How can I get lua 5.1 for lazy.nvim / luarocks on macOS?
the :checkhealth lazy  is complaining about Lua 5.1 not being installed.
- WARNING lua version 5.1 needed, but found Lua 5.4.7 Copyright (c) 1994-2024 lua.org, PUC-Rio
- WARNING {lua5.1} or {lua} or {lua-5.1} version 5.1 not installed

From https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim/issues/1570#issuecomment-2194329169

luarocks for Neovim plugins requires Lua 5.1, that is completely correct.

I tried to install Lua 5.1 with homebrew but lua 5.1 is too old
brew install lua@5.1 
Error: lua@5.1 has been disabled because it is deprecated upstream!

So how can I fix this lazy.nvim warnings?

Installing lua 5.1 from sources it's not that complicated
wget https://www.lua.org/ftp/lua-5.1.5.tar.gz
tar xzf lua-5.1.5.tar.gz
cd lua-5.1.5
make macosx
mkdir ~/opt
make INSTALL_TOP=$HOME/opt/lua@5.1 install
mkdir -p ~/.local/bin
ln -s ~/opt/lua@5.1/bin/lua ~/.local/bin/lua5.1
export PATH=~/.local/bin/:$PATH # put ~/.local/bin in the path in your .basrc or .zshrc
nvim  


now :checkhealth lazy finds the lua5.1 executable in the path:
luarocks ~
- checking `luarocks` installation
- OK no plugins require `luarocks`, so you can ignore any warnings below
- OK {luarocks} `/usr/local/bin/luarocks 3.11.1`
- OK {lua5.1} `Lua 5.1.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2012 Lua.org, PUC-Rio`


you can make this a self-answered question - I don't recall the exact terminology. This works well.
